# MailKit delete Emails Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, email, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mailkit

I am using mailkit on monotouch xamarin. I am creating an app that will receive emails(email client). I give to the user the option to choose if he is using Pop3 or IMAP connection protocol. My issue is that I cant find solution on how he can  delete a message on Pop3 and on IMAP.
I have tried to use this code:

```
client.Inbox.AddFlags (new int[] { index }, MessageFlags.Deleted);
```

from this post: [MailKit Delete single message from gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677464/mailkit-delete-single-message-from-gmail)
but is not seems to work for me.
My code for capturing the Pop3 acount emails is

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential (Convert.ToString (username), Convert.ToString (password));

    var uri = new Uri (Convert.ToString ("pops://"+pop3));

    using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource ()) {
        client.Connect (uri, cancel.Token);

        var _emailItems=new List<EmailItem>() ;

        client.Authenticate (credentials, cancel.Token);
        string[] mycell = new string[200];
        int count = client.GetMessageCount (cancel.Token);
        int lastcount;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            lastcount = (count - 1) - i;
            var message = client.GetMessage (lastcount, cancel.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different protocols have different ways of deleting messages.

For POP3, this is how you would delete a message:

```
client.DeleteMessage (lastcount, cancel.Token);
```

(Note: unless you are actually allowing the user to cancel the operations, you do not need to use `cancel.Token`)

The other way of deleting messages that you pasted is meant for IMAP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code but i have not any results. The message doesn't be deleted. When i connected again with the server the message displayed again.

Comment: Are you disconnecting with client.Disconnect (true)? If not, the POP3 server will not actually delete them.

Comment: You are great! yes now it works for me. Can you also help me on how can i delete the message if i use imap?

Comment: The other post you linked to explains how to delete messages with IMAP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677464/mailkit-delete-single-message-from-gmail